# Multiple errors in my android manifest after adding intents due to launchURL package

Tags: flutter

the title says it all. I'm having trouble to build my apk. I fixed most errors that have appeared to me. However, my android manifest has 24 yellow errors. How can I fix them, if I have only changed the intents, and after removing them the errors still continues to impair apk build

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.farma"
android:versionCode="TODO"
android:versionName="TODO"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
<!-- If your app checks for call support -->
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>


android: usesCleartextTraffic="true"
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    tools:ignore="Instantiatable,WrongManifestParent"
    tools:targetApi="honeycomb">
    <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
         the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
         while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
         to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
     This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
<meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to find the error , i think you edited some where the file

to save time create a new project and copy the manifest file  into your project and edit it "keep the same format and copy all the content"